# Canvas.Width and Canvas.height returns -1#.IND

Tags: wpf, vb.net, canvas

when i try to get the width and the height of my canvas both returns -1#.IND

```
Dim ControlWidth as double = MyCanvas.Width 
Dim ControlHeight as double = MyCanvas.Height
```

Comment: use ActualWidth & ActualHeight if you want the size of the element. Width & Height are user set properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-1#.IND` is [**`Double.NaN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan(v=vs.110).aspx), which means the width and height are set to `auto`. To get the dimensions in pixels(/units?) instead you should use [**`ActualWidth`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`ActualHeight`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim ControlWidth As Double = MyCanvas.ActualWidth 
Dim ControlHeight As Double = MyCanvas.ActualHeight
```

Comment: IND, not INF, short for "indefinite".  In other words, Double.NaN.